# Empilhar varios arquivos txt usando pandas

Tags: python, pandas, txt

Queria fazer uma rotina que acumule os dados que extraio do google analytics todo dia, porém o meu código apresenta um erro que não consigo resolver:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

my_dir = 'N:/E-Commerce/Relatorios/Bases/Source/Canais'
filelist = []
filesList = []
os.chdir(my_dir)
for files in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(files)
    filelist.append(fileName) 
    filesList.append(files) 
df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in filelist:
    frame = pd.read_csv(f)
    df = df.append(frame)
print(df)
```

ele apresenta um erro que não consegue encontrar o arquivo 'b 20180401':

FileNotFoundError: File b'20180401' does not exist

no entanto, o arquivo tem nome somente 20180401 (um arquivo por dia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lista que sob a qual você esta iterando, é a lista que contém os nomes dos arquivos sem a extensão `.txt` logo, estes arquivos realmente não existem no seu path.

Tente trocar:

```
for f in filelist:
    ....
```

Por

```
for f in filesList:
    ....
```

Que deverá funcionar como o esperado, afinal, é nesta lista que contém os nomes do arquvios completos (com extensão).

Outro ponto (o que não interfer no funcionamento do teu código), tente dar nome que fazem sentido para suas váriaveis, neste caso mesmo é muito facil confundir `filelist` com `filesList` mesmo os dois tendos conteudos e talves propósitos diferentes.

Espero ter ajudado :D

Comment: Ajudou sim, valeu! mas ainda não consegui criar o DF pois me dá o erro 

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

pelo que pesquisei parece um problema do python em iterar em .txt

sabe como proceder neste caso ?